# creating a method to read in integers

Tags: java, arrays, int, java.util.scanner

I have coded a section of code which reads in four quarterly trading figures and adds them to four arrays.

Here is my code,the array initialisers here are from a previous variation where I just added the figures in,my new variation takes the figures in from the user.

```
 /**
int [] quarterOne = {12,8,12,21,14,23};
int [] quarterTwo= {24,11,14,23,14,24};
int [] quarterThree = {26,7,14,26,17,26};
int [] quarterFour = {17,9,15,31,18,35};
**/




int[] quarterOne;
quarterOne=new int[6];

int[] quarterTwo;
quarterTwo=new int[6];

int[] quarterThree;
quarterThree=new int[6];

int[] quarterFour;
quarterFour=new int[6];

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;

      System.out.println("Please enter Q1,Q2,Q3 AND Q4 figures for first broker:");


for (int i=0; i<6; i++){

    quarterOne[i]=input.nextInt();
    quarterTwo[i]=input.nextInt();
    quarterThree[i]=input.nextInt();
    quarterFour[i]=input.nextInt();
if (i<=4) System.out.println("Please enter Q1,Q2,Q3 AND Q4 figures for next broker:");
}
```

I have to do another variation of this section which involves making it into a method to be called from the main which can read in the figures .
I cant figure out how it should look, if it returns a value or is void and what parameters I should use.

Comment: A void method where you hand in the arrays to be filled is probably easier. You have four arrays and you can only return one thing from a method. If you want to return the arrays from the method you would need to use some kind of multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally up to the developer on what the method should return. Something like this would work. You need to call the  Scanner inputs from the main method. Then you can send the scanner inputs into the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ClassName varName = ClassName();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //ask user to enter in data
    int[] array1;
    int[] array2;
    int[] array3;
    int[] array4;
    varName.setQuarterlyValues(array1, array2, array3, array4, input);
}


public void setQuarterlyValues(int[] quarterOne, int[] quarterTwo, int[] quarterThree,    int[] quarterFour, Scanner input)
{
  for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
   quarterOne[i]=input.nextInt();
   quarterTwo[i]=input.nextInt();
   quarterThree[i]=input.nextInt();
   quarterFour[i]=input.nextInt();
   if (i<=5)
   { 
     System.out.println("Please enter Q1,Q2,Q3 AND Q4 figures for next broker:");
   }
  }
}
```